# Line Tooltip in Epilog doesn't work

Tags: tooltip

Authors of different demonstrations from Wolfram Demonstrations Project have used Tooltip for lines in Epilog. Is it possible, that in previous versions of Mathematica it worked? In Mathematica 13 it doesn’t work. For example

```
Plot[1/x, {x, 0, 10}, Epilog -> Tooltip[Point[{2, 0.5}], "Point"]]
```

works. But for line

```
Plot[1/x, {x, 0, 10}, Epilog -> Tooltip[Line[{{2, 0}, {2, 0.5}}], "Line"]]
```

it doesn’t work, nothing appears.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. Please report it to: support@wolfram.com

Comment: Use `Show[Plot[Tooltip[1/x, HoldForm[1/x]], {x, 0, 10}], Graphics[{Tooltip[Line[{{2, 0}, {2, 0.5}}], "Line"]}]]`

Comment: Work fine in  v11.3 but not for v13.1, it is a bug.

Comment: Not fixed in 13.2 pre-release "13.2.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (October 12, 2022)"